# Changing a control's property via delegate

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, user-interface, delegates

I am not sure on why this code works when called from the UI thread, but not otherwise:

```
Delegate Sub CtrlPropertyChangeDelegate(ByRef ControlProperty As Object, ByVal NewValue As Object)

Sub CtrlPropertyChange(ByRef ControlProperty As Object, ByVal NewValue As Object)

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New CtrlPropertyChangeDelegate(AddressOf CtrlPropertyChange), ControlProperty, NewValue)
    Else
        ControlProperty = NewValue
    End If

End Sub
```

It's supposed to take a control's property (such as Form1.Text) and change its value. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: When you don't need to invoke you modify the `ControlProperty` reference directly. However when you call `Invoke()` the parameters are passed as an array of objects, where every array item is passed by value. This is the standard behaviour of arrays and is not possible to change. -- Use @MrGadget's solution, that calls the method directly and still passes `ControlProperty` by reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that a ByRef parameter cannot be used in a lambda expression @VisualVincent

Comment: But the lambda expression should behave like any normal method, and calling another method that has a `ByRef` parameter shouldn't matter. I'll try it out, and if I don't get it to work I have an alternative solution you can use.

Comment: I'll be posting my solution soon. Currently working on it.

Comment: ASSIDE: I don't know about you guys but I find this one of the more annoying "features" of dot.net. Yes I know, thread safety... blah blah. But I don't like constraints like this that generate an error instead of a warning. IMHO.. ya I know it's not thread safe... but in this case.. I don't care... should be an option.

Comment: However, if you are doing a lot of that, you might want to consider a different approach that lets the form handle the UI update based on some other trigger.

Comment: @Trevor : `I don't like constraints like this that generate an error instead of a warning` - I'm not sure what you're referring to...

Comment: @VisualVincent the whole point of this exercise is to allow you to write to the UI from another thread.... VB crashes if you try to do that without going through these work-arounds..  Where is the "Ignore Cross Thread UI References" Checkbox....

Comment: @Trevor : [**`Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136030/discussion-between-trevor-and-visual-vincent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in my comment, once you pass `ControlProperty` to the parameters of `Control.Invoke()` it is no longer passed by reference.

Here's a solution using [**Reflection**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx). You just pass the name of the property and the value you want to give it to the `SetProperty` method. I've declared it as an extension method, thus it must be put in a public module:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Thread-safely sets the property of a control to the specified value. Be sure that the value is of the correct type.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Control">The control which's property to set.</param>
    ''' <param name="PropertyName">The name of the property to set.</param>
    ''' <param name="Value">The value to give the property.</param>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub SetProperty(ByVal Control As Control, ByVal PropertyName As String, ByVal Value As Object)
        If Control.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Control.Invoke(Sub() Control.SetProperty(PropertyName, Value))
        Else
            Control.GetType().InvokeMember(PropertyName, _
                                            BindingFlags.SetProperty _
                                             Or BindingFlags.IgnoreCase _
                                              Or BindingFlags.Public _
                                               Or BindingFlags.Instance _
                                                Or BindingFlags.Static, _
                                            Nothing, Control, New Object() {Value})
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
For x = 1 To 256
    Label1.SetProperty("Text", ((x * 100) / 256) & "%")
    ProgressBar1.SetProperty("Value", x)
    Thread.Sleep(15)
Next
```

**Important:** When using this you must make sure that the value you're giving the property is of the correct type, since implicit conversions are not performed. So if the property you set is of type `String`, then attempting to set it to an `Integer` will throw an exception.

Comment: @Kyle : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

Updated to incorporate [@VisualVincent's Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42317000/3992902), which should be marked as the correct answer.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Rand As New Random
    Private Done As Boolean = True
    Private WordList() As String = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"}
    Private Colors() As Color = {Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Gray, Color.Yellow}

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Done Then
            Done = False
            Task.Run(Sub() DoSomething())
        Else
            Done = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        RandomChange()
    End Sub

    Sub DoSomething()
        Me.Button1.SetProperty("Text", "Stop")

        Do Until Done
            RandomChange()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Loop

        Me.Button1.SetProperty("Text", "Start")
    End Sub

    Sub RandomChange()
        Select Case Rand.Next(1, 6)
            Case 1
                Me.ProgressBar1.SetProperty("Value", Rand.Next(10, 90))
            Case 2
                Me.TextBox1.SetProperty("Text", WordList(Rand.Next(0, 4)))
            Case 3
                Me.Label1.SetProperty("Text", WordList(Rand.Next(0, 4)))
            Case 4
                Me.CheckBox1.SetProperty("Checked", Not Me.CheckBox1.Checked)
            Case 5
                Me.SetProperty("BackColor", Colors(Rand.Next(0, 4)))
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This should work. It passes the parameter by reference to itself like it should. However there is no need to call `Refresh()` on any control since they will automatically redraw when you change their text.

Comment: It says that a ByRef parameter cannot be used in a lambda expression -- that's why I tried using a delegate

Comment: Replaced my answer with a test case...will update again as answer is worked out.

Comment: You can't update it because whenever it is passed by value it will be a new string/integer/whatever so long it's an instance type. It appears you cannot make it this easy when mixing it with thread-safety.

Comment: I have posted my solution. :)